# using try catch when declaring variables

Tags: javascript, variables, try-catch

For one reason or other ( I'm not going to go into why here) I need to use javascript to get the values of 12 hidden input fields and set a variable for each value.

I am not sure what the best approach for this would be. I'd like to be able to get the values and if they are not created i.e. the input fields are not there then id like to generate an error.

Would using a try / catch be good for this or should I simply be using typeof to check the variables have been created?

would putting them in an array as well so i can loop through to check their existance be a good idea?

thanks

Comment: Show us some code so we can start it from there.

Comment: Seems to me that all of this is overkill. If you want to throw an error if they're not there, why check at all? Let the error occur where / when they are used. Or if you want to raise the error immediately, you could just use if (!x) throw new Error (...)

Comment: thanks i don't have any code right now i purely want to discuss the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easy way of doing it. try-catch is rather heavy. Also, where would you throw the error to? Instead of unwinding your flow on error, collect your errors into a well structured response. That way if your first one is missing, but the other X are not, then you still get some work done.

```
if ( typeof( something ) !== "undefined" ) { doStuff(); }
```

Otherwise, I'd need more information to help you with your question.

Comment: Thanks Chris, i need to set it up so if any of the variables are missing then output an error i.e. put some text on the screen saying there is an error

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("someID")){
// add the value since the input exists
}
else{
// skip or use default - and inform if need be
}
```

Example implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/zVz6h/1/

Code:

```
 function getValueArray(idArray){
var valArray = [];
for(var i=0;i<idArray.length;i++){    
    if(document.getElementById(idArray[i])){
    valArray.push(document.getElementById(idArray[i]).value);       
    }
    else{
    valArray.push("not defined");
    }
}
    return valArray;

}

var txtIDs = ["txt1","txt2","txt3","txt4","txt5","txt6","txt7","txt8"];


alert(getValueArray(txtIDs));
```

Comment: would it not be better to get the values and put them in an array to loop through them to check each one so if one does not exist it throws an error?

Comment: Know you accepted another answer. Just wanted to show you how this approch could be implemented...

Comment: thanks I appreciate your imt eon this shame i cant tick more than one

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple function that will check to see that exactly 12 input elements are included on the page. Please provide more information if you need th check that individual input elements are present.

```
  function SaveInputValues() {

    var inps = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (inps.length !== 12) {
      return alert("There must be exactly 12 input elements. You have included " + inps.length + ".");
    }
    var vals = [];
    for (i = 0; i < inps.length; i++) vals.push(inps[i].value);
    inps = null; // provides closure
  }
```

Comment: thanks that is a different approach i didn't think of. there will be other inputs on the page but theses will be wrapped in a div so i can use that to reference them.